# How to change custom module title in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created a custom module which is connected with about menu . In my custom module the hook menu is

```
$items['user_custom_floornews'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Login Axon Connect',
    'title_label'     => t('Login Axon Connect'),
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_custom_floornews_form'), //put the name of the form here
    'access callback' => TRUE
    );
```

In this case the page title is "Login Axon Connect" but when I change it to "User About" the page title does not change from "Login Axon Connect" to "User About" . I have cleared cache and try all the methods but "Login Axon Connect" page title does not change .Any help regarding this would be appreciable.

=============

```
<?php
function user_custom_floornews_menu()
{
    $items = array();

    $items['user_custom_floornews'] = array(
'title'            => 'User About',
'page callback'    => 'user_custom_call_back',
'access callback' => TRUE
);

    return $items;
}
function user_custom_floornews_form($form, $form_state){




    return $form;
}
?>
```

this is the total code I put in the module but still its holding previous title , I have cleared cache but nothing changed

Comment: Please use 'function  user_custom_call_back(){ $pageContent = '';
    return $pageContent;}' replace function user_custom_floornews_form($form, $form_state){..., if it's still not work,, never mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the way but check "Login Axon Connect" in your database and replace it with your title

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should remove this line:

```
'title_label'     => t('Login Axon Connect'),
```

I tried following code it's working well..

```
$items['user_custom_floornews'] = array(
'title'            => 'User About',
'page callback'    => 'user_custom_call_back',
'access callback' => TRUE
);
```

[image]

Comment: Tang I have followed the same thing but it still holding my previous module title..